# SQL combine basic order by and custom order by

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I am using Oracle database and I am trying to combine a basic `Order By` and a custom one in one of my query.

Here's my table :

```
table1 
-----------------
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4
```

I am trying to order it like that :

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4 FROM table1
ORDER BY C1, C2, C3, ( 
CASE C4
   WHEN C4 = 'value1' THEN 1
   WHEN C4 = 'value2' THEN 2
   WHEN C4 = 'value3' THEN 3
END
)
```

But I'm getting "Missing keyword" and I can't find which one, any ideas?

Comment: You mix two different `case` versions. Either `case when c4 = value1 then ... ` or `case c4 when value1 then ..`.

Comment: @jarlh Oh yeah that was my idiot mistake, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4 FROM table1
ORDER BY C1, C2, C3, ( 
CASE 
   WHEN C4 = 'value1' THEN 1
   WHEN C4 = 'value2' THEN 2
   WHEN C4 = 'value3' THEN 3
END
)
```

OR

```
SELECT C1,C2,C3,C4 FROM table1
ORDER BY C1, C2, C3, ( 
CASE C4
   WHEN 'value1' THEN 1
   WHEN 'value2' THEN 2
   WHEN 'value3' THEN 3
END
)
```

Comment: yep as said before @jarlh that was a mistake from me, I will validate your answer when I can :)